# R Remove columns from a data.frame with other df

Tags: r, dataframe, drop

Hello I have 2 dataframes:

df1 looks like:

[image]

and the df2 looks like:

[image]

I have noticied that the df1 has point symbol (.), while df2 has "-". It is weird because both of them, if I open with a text editor or excel, they have "-".

What I need is to drop all the columns of df1 that match with a value of df2.
I have used this:

```
DataGenSample = df1[,!(names(df1) %in% df2)]
#DataGenSample <- df1[ , !(colnames(df1) %in% df2)]
```

but there is no change.

All the [Data](https://www.transfernow.net/AT5yMN042020) can be foun here. Whith the code that I have used.

```
# Data (df1):
DataGen <- read.table("data_CNA.txt",sep="\t", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

# Samples (df2):
DeleteSample <- read.table("MuestrasEliminar.txt",sep="\t", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

```
#Delete columns:

#DataGenSample = DataGen[,!(names(DataGen) %in% DeleteSample)]
DataGenSample <- DataGen[ , !(colnames(DataGen) %in% DeleteSample)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `-` vs `.`.

When you read in the data, your read command probably has an argument like `check.names` that changes the names to make them "standard" R names - which means no punctuation other than `_` and `.`. If you set `check.names = FALSE` the original names will be kept, and your code should work just fine.

Comment: hello @Gregor Thomas, I did not know about that command, but it did not work when I've tried to drop the column.

Comment: The problem remaining is that `DeleteSample` is a data frame, but you're using it like a vector. Try ` !(colnames(DataGen) %in% DeleteSample$SAMPLE_ID)`, or whatever the relevant column name is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out that you need to convert your df in vector first:

```
vecDeleteSample <- DeleteSample$SAMPLE_ID
```

And then you can drop the mathing columns of your vector/list:

```
DataGenSample <- DataGen[,!(names(DataGen) %in% vecDeleteSample)]
```